# Javac bash file on debian not working properly

Tags: java, bash, batch-file, debian, javac

I need a quick conversion for my compiler and run batch files.

I tried looking up the documentation for java and im not understanding why im getting errors with the current command I am preforming.

My current command:
    `javac -d bin -cp lib/*: -sourcepath src src/com/rs/*.java`

My current error
http://puu.sh/92E7H/c75bc01448.png

This does work on windows and all of the javac options are the same on debian so I am unsure as to why this is happening

Thanks.

Comment: The file is definitely there, like I said above the command works in windows with the same directory paths nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It says "file not found." In most cases, that means that the file is not found. You probably misspelled something or are in the wrong directory.